# How to logout a KDE session in a TTY?

Tags: command-line, console, kubuntu, kde-plasma-5, logout

I encounter a KDE desktop(Kubuntu-20.04.4) fault, and now it stalled and does NOT response any operation, I can NOT logout in any normal ways.

But this computer is running a important service, and should **NOT** be stopped or restarted.

I switched to the tty console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2, and logged-in as root to check the producing service status.

Fortunately, the producing service and DB are working normally.
Now I need to kill/restart KDE desktop, so as to let me can re-login desktop.
I can only operate the computer with command line interface at console.

How do I get that?
Thanx!

Comment: You have access to the command line, rebooting should be as easy as `sudo reboot`. With a reboot you ensure that the machine is in a known working state. Restarting plasma is as simple as [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out) You shouldn't be running a webserver on a GUI machine, it got way too much stuff running that can introduce problems.

Comment: Doesn't `init 3 ; init 5` or the systemd equivalent work?

Comment: @mashuptwice The op has stated that it cannot be restarted.

Comment: Does [kwin - Can I restart the KDE Plasma Desktop without logging out? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you gentlemen! I tried `kstart5 plasmashel` and others, before I asked this question.

Comment: @Leon Why did you not include that in your question? You could have prevented 2 people from suggesting the exact same thing you've tried by mentioning what you've tried.. Also: the title of your question says you want to log out but it seems you want to restart KDE and login. Also it is unclear what your goal is after you've logged in successfully, do you need to regain control to GUI apps on the stalled session or are you simply unfamiliar with the command line? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1737750/edit) your question accordingly.